# From [parentid, name] directory dict to full paths dict

Tags: python, dictionary, path, filesystems

I have a dict of directories as `[parentid, name]` like this:

```
D = {0: [-1, 'C:'],
     1: [0, 'BLAH'], 
     2: [0, 'TEMP'], 
     3: [1, 'BOOO'], 
     4: [1, 'AZAZ'], 
     5: [2, 'ABCD']}
```

I'd like to go from this to full paths:

```
FULLPATHS = {}
for key, path in D.iteritems():
    newpath = path[1]
    if path[0] != -1:
         newpath = FULLPATHS[path[0]] + '\\' + newpath
    FULLPATHS[key] = newpath
```

It works:

```
 {0: 'C:', 1: 'C:\\BLAH', 2: 'C:\\TEMP', 3: 'C:\\BLAH\\BOOO', 4: 'C:\\BLAH\\AZAZ', 5: 'C:\\TEMP\\ABCD'}
```

But now the tricky part comes if the keys are non-increasing directory IDs:

```
 D = {0: [-1, 'C:'],
     7: [0, 'TEMP'], 
     3: [122, 'BOOO'], 
     4: [122, 'AZAZ'], 
     5: [7, 'ABCD'],
     122: [0, 'BLAH']}
```

And it is often like this in NTFS MasterFileTable (that I'm reading).

The idea could be: *"When arriving on `3: [122, 'BOOO']`, let's wait and postpone this one for later, once dir #122 will be processed later"*. But this would require many successive loops to be sure that everything is correctly done.

**How to go from a `[parentid, name]` directory scheme to full paths?**

Note: this problem is not specific to Python, so I'm not looking for `os.path` solutions but rather a general problem.

Comment: IS sorting your list `L` by the parent key out of the question ?

Comment: Wait, **random**? I thought parentid is an index of parent in your list `L`. If it is not, then how do you know which directory is `9`?

Comment: @Błotosmętek : I edited : in my real situation, the keys are int32 IDs, but non increasing. They look random unique IDs.

Comment: @Błotosmętek yes, root has key `0` and parentid `-1`. But in real life, there can be hundreds of thousands of dirs, and subsubsubsubfolders, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying a solution like this: if a parent has not been *"full-path-ed"* yet, do it first, once for all!

```
FULLPATHS = {0: 'C:'}

def do(id):
    parentid = D[id][0]
    name = D[id][1]
    if id not in FULLPATHS:
        if parentid not in FULLPATHS:
            do(parentid)
        FULLPATHS[id] = FULLPATHS[parentid] + '\\' + name

for k, v in D.iteritems():
    do(k)

print FULLPATHS  

#{0: 'C:', 3: 'C:\\BLAH\\BOOO', 4: 'C:\\BLAH\\AZAZ', 5: 'C:\\TEMP\\ABCD', 7: 'C:\\TEMP', 122: 'C:\\BLAH'}
```

Answer (score 1):

A possibility: for every element go up the chain till you reach root.

```
FULLPATHS=dict()
for k in D:
    parent = D[k][0]
    chain = [ D[k][1] ]
    while parent != -1: # here I assume root's parent is always -1
        chain.append(D[parent][1])
        parent = D[parent][0]
    FULLPATHS[k] = '\\'.join(reversed(chain))
```

or even, taking advantage of already made prefix paths:

```
FULLPATHS = { 0: 'C:' }
for k in D:
    i = k
    chain = []
    while i not in FULLPATHS:
        chain.append(D[i][1])
            i = D[i][0]
    FULLPATHS[k] = '\\'.join([FULLPATHS[i]] + list(reversed(chain)))

print(FULLPATHS)
```

Comment: Thanks! Good solution I think, except that if the average distance from root is m on filesystem, this will require O(n * m).

Comment: See improved solution.

Comment: Thanks! I tried [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45015330/1422096) in the meantime, what do you think, which one do you think will be more efficient on a big filesystem? It seems difficult to compare right now...

Comment: For learning purpose, it would be very interesting to benchmark both, but how to do that? Generating a random directory tree structure of 10 millions elements? I'm interested if you have any idea!